# swift3・alamofireimageでPHPから出力したイメージを表示したい

Tags: swift, php, swift3, 画像, alamofire

swift3でalamofireimageを利用してPHPで生成した画像(jpg)を取得・表示したい。

前提として
・alamofireimage自体は正常に稼働しています。
・サーバー上の静的なjpgファイルの場合、問題なく取得できます。
・PHP出力画像もブラウザから確認すると正常に生成されています。

以下がトライしている箇所のコードになります。
swift側の処理

```
//ViewControllerの
//override func viewDidLoad() {の中に記述しています。
//(1)JPG画像への直リンクの場合はうまくいきます。
self.imgURL = "https://.../path/sample.jpg"
//(2)PHP(生成画像)へのリンクの場合、画像が取得できません。
self.imgURL = "https://.../path/output.php?param=sample"
let ImageURL = NSURL(string: self.imgURL)!
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "myplaceholder.png")!
self.mapImageView.af_setImage(withURL: ImageURL as URL , placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

PHP側の処理

```
#PHPにて動的にJPG画像を出力
#※今回はSVGデータからJPGを生成しています。
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob($SVGData);
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
header('Content-Type: image/'.$image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
```

どのようにすればPHPから出力した画像を(alamofireimageで)取得することができるのでしょうか。
アドバイスを何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

alamofireimageが、どのheaderを処理で利用しているか判らないのですが、Content-Typeが

```
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
header('Content-Type: image/'.$image->getImageFormat());
```

の実行で　image/jpg　出力になっていると思われます。jpg画像だけの出力なら

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

固定で出力がよいかと。
必要ならば　画像名、画像サイズをheaderで渡してあげましょう。

```
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="img name"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $image->getImageSize());
```